# GNU Autotools - How to handle required but possibly missing headers?

Tags: c, autotools

I was wondering about the best-practice solution of handling required headers with GNU Autotools. This is one line from my `configure.ac`

```
AC_CHECK_HEADERS_ONCE(argp.h)
```

If the `argp.h` is missing on a system, then configure will just proclaim

```
...
checking for argp.h... no
...
```

but do nothing about it. Of course, the program will fail to compile, because the expected header does not exist, and wrapping the include in `#ifdef HAVE_ARGP_H` directives, and possibly adding an `#else #error [...]` construct would do what I want, but it seems rather tedious.

Is there a good way to error out on missing but required headers on **configure** time as opposed to compile time?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `AC_CHECK_HEADERS_ONCE` call with:

```
AC_CHECK_HEADER([argp.h], [], AC_MSG_ERROR([cannot find required header argp.h]))
```

This variant won't define `HAVE_ARGP_H`, but you don't need that anyway since your code requires that header unconditionally.  The error stops the configure process.